# How does setting up our environment for the course differ from what we'd be doing in production?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I was able to set up my development environment for the course thanks to the help from others in the discord and the guides they developed.  I understand that this helps us set up the plutus playground in our local environment for the course.

My question is: How does this setup differ from what we'd end up using for a contract in a production environment?  Is there additional infrastructure required to run smart contracts in mainnet production?

Answer (score 1):

Later in the course, I think we'll get into using PAB and submitting smart contracts on-chain. At the first stage here, the focus is on simulated contracts. There's some additional steps to get the hashes that need to go into the tx and other things.

Answer (score 0):

I did the Plutus Pinoer Cohort 3 and can confirm there is an End-2-End example in the course that comes out near the end.

As the previous cohorts are online there's no reason you cant watch those videos in advance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfWKxdli4eI&list=PLNEK_Ejlx3x2sBWXHdFBRgkzPF6N-1LVi